# When doing ajax in tabulator, how can I add a column apart from the ajax?

Tags: tabulator

I'm making my table based on AJAX, it works fine, but now I want to add a column called "Operations", where I want to put buttons like 'edit', 'delete'.

How can I do this? I somehow can't find the answer in the docs, maybe I'm missing a word or something :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, found an answer, if anyone's interested:

We add a column with a 'formatter', like this:

```
    { title:"Operations", field:"", formatter:operations }
```

And then e.g.:

```
    function operations(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){ 
        return `
            <i class="fa fa-times" title = 'Delete' data-id = ${ cell.id}></i>
        `;
    }
```